# gRPC compiling error with Clang/Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, clang, grpc

For a C++ project, I need to use gRPC. everything went well with MSVC143 compiler, And I did.
but I'm using Clang compiler in Visual Studio 2022. So, it must build by Clang.
I tired to do this, but, I'm getting too many errors at the compile time.
Here, you can see them:
[image]

I did the whole instructions according to [this tutorial](http://youtube.com/watch?v=LxHV-KNEG3k). As I've said before. It works very well when I choose MSVC as compiler.

It's pretty weird. What should I do?

Future Information:
Visual Studio 2022(it's the latest version).
Clang version 13.0.1(it's the latest version as well).
CMake version 3.24.1(it's the latest version as well).

[This article](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/grpc-grpc/+/HEAD/BUILDING.md) says These steps require. I did them as well.

> Windows To prepare for cmake + Microsoft Visual C++ compiler build
>
> Install Visual Studio 2015 or 2017 (Visual C++ compiler will be used).
> Install Git. Install CMake. Install Active State Perl (choco install
> activeperl) - required by boringssl Install Go (choco install golang)
>
> - required by boringssl Install yasm and add it to PATH (choco install yasm) - required by boringssl (Optional) Install Ninja (choco install
>   ninja)

Comment: Please show the compiler output as text not as a screenshot of the error list

Comment: Also use the error message is a web search.

Comment: I've tried to  leave  Output or Error Lists. but It's too long, and it's not possible.

Comment: Almost all of the errors are like `could not open 'third_party\...'`

Comment: Here you'll  see the final result `========== Build: 190 succeeded, 266 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`

Comment: Just post up to the first few errors, we don't need the entire log